# Why does the .jmx file is not running in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I'm getting an error when I tried to run a jmx file in Jmeter.

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-09-19 11:49:31 IST
Load time: 11
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2255
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2255
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: connect timed out
```

Response headers:

```
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Answer (score 0):

The .jmx file is running normally, the error you're getting indicates that JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) couldn't establish connection with the application under test within the bounds of the maximum connect time defined.

1. Make sure that the application under test is reachable from the machine where JMeter is running using [telnet client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_clients) or equivalent. If it isn't - you need to contact your network administrator to clarify what's going on and why application is not reachable
2. If you can access the application under test using telnet command it might be the case you need to increase timeouts under [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults/)

   [image]